# Smooth section of Hodge bundle ($F^pH^k$) can be viewed as a smooth form of type$F^pH^k(X,C)$ over$ X$,$ X\rightarrow B$ is an analytic family.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I think it is due to Kodaira. could someone explain the idea that Kodaira come up with this.

maybe I shouldn't say"can be viewed as". I really mean the smooth form restrict on each fibre is just the value of the section at that base point.

I think it is related to the property of elliptic operator and use PDE tools. But I cannot see through it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can define a connection at the level of the de Rham complexes rather than only at the level of a cohomology bundle. (This not so dissimilar to what is done for Hitchin's connection: it operates on the infinite dimensional space of  $C^\infty$ sections of a line bundle, but happens to preserve holomorphicity.) One can define a notion of flat sections in the de Rham complex bundle. (See Peters and Steenbrink's ''Mixed Hodge Structures'' for a treatment using $\mathcal{D}$-modules.) This connection agrees with the Gauss-Manin connection on the Hodge (cohomology) bundle.

Take any flat section $s(t)$ ($t$ varies in the base). Now at a base point, say $t_0$, choose a form $\omega$ living on the fiber $X_{t_0}$ representing this cohomology class, i.e., $[\omega] = s(t_0)$. Solving the relevant differential equation gives a form $\omega(t)$ smoothly varying over the fibers such that $[\omega(t)] = s(t)$.

For an arbitrary section $\sigma(t)$, one can expand this in terms of a basis of flat sections $s_i(t)$:
 $$\sigma(t) = \sum f_i(t)s_i(t) = \sum f_i [\omega_i(t)] = [\sum f_i \omega_i(t)]$$

Comment: By the way, Feng, you should try to put the "math" into the body of the question rather than the title.

Comment: I also would like to see the Kodaira reference. Please post if you find it!!

Comment: Thank you for making up the answer in details. I Think Donu's idea is good(refer to the proof of relative twisted De Rham theorem). Right now I realize the PDE proof of that question should be more general but too computable and awkward. I will try to find it on Kodaira's book variation of complex structure.

Comment: Because I want to draw attention from you :-) I mean the title.